# Problem with php handling ajax in the same file

Tags: html, ajax, local-storage

I have a serious problem, I can't receive data sent by ajax in php. I've read many tutorial about that but it still not resolved. So if you guys have the magic solution, it'll make my day.
Here is the code, **note that it is in the same file problem.php**.
**assocStored is an array or object**, and **it have the right data if I check it on jvascript**

```js
window.onload = function(e){
        var assocStored = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("associes"));

        $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                data : {"problem" : assocStored},
                success : function(res){
                    console.log("action performed successfully");
                }
        })
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <h3>php</h3>
    <?php
         var_dump ($_POST);
         if( isset($_POST['problem']) ){
            foreach ($_POST['problem'] as $associe) {
            echo($associe["sex"]." ".$associe["firstname"]." ".$associe["lastname"]);
            }
            exit;
         }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You can view the send request in the network tab, and make sure it sends right data, not by js.

Comment: Yes, it's realy in the localstorage of my browser named **associes**

Comment: I commented below. So my mean is checking your send request like method, parameter, type of data, etc...

Answer (score 0):

As my comment above, I guess your request send a GET method.

In your code, you are using `type` is `POST` but `type` is an alias for `method`. You should use `type` if you are using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.

So you can modify your `ajax` to here:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    data : { "problem" : JSON.stringify(assocStored) }, // convert to json
    dataType: "json", // add type
    success : function(res){
        console.log("action performed successfully");
    }
})
```

If it continues not working, add this code to ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    data : { "problem" : JSON.stringify(assocStored) }, // convert to json
    dataType: "json", // add type
    beforeSend: function(req) {
        if (req && req.overrideMimeType) {
            req.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
        }
    },
    success : function(res){
        console.log("action performed successfully");
    }
})
```

I hope it works.

Comment: No it doesn't  .

Comment: Sorry, I forgot `assocStored` is an array, check my answer again, I hope it works.

Comment: Oh, try `data : JSON.stringify({ "problem" : assocStored }),`